# Targeting plain text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to isolate (and then manipulate) quote block formatted in common newsreader and email-client manner.

The HTML:

```
<p>
  Hello there!
  <br />
  I'm great, how are you?
  <br />
  <br />
  Someone wrote:
  <br />
  > Greetings,
  <br />
  > How are you?
</p>
```

I need to target all the lines that start with >, and hide them as a collapsable block. In the above example everything bellow "Someone wrote:" would then be hidden, saved as a variable and the end result produced by JS would be:

```
<p>
  Hello there!
  <br />
  I'm great, how are you?
  <br />
  <br />
  Someone wrote:
  <br />
  <a href="#">Click to expand</a>
</p>
```

Gmail does the same thing, but it serverside wraps the quotation block in a `<div>`, due to the specific nature of my project the complete process has to be done by JS alone.
I'm working with the jQuery framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you'll want to investicate .contents() http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together an example for you at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.me/97e73af074f23043c5f06c632d0268a6). Here is the code with comments added.

HTML

```
<p>
  Hello there!
  <br />
  I'm great, how are you?
  <br />
  <br />
  Someone wrote:
  <br />
  > Greetings,
  <br />
  > How are you?
  <br />
  <br />
  Someone else wrote:
  <br />
  > I like turtles
  <br />
  <br />
  > Someone odd person wrote:
  <br />
  > > You smell like cheese
  <br />
  > > and now I'm hungry
  <br />
  <br />
  and that's the end,
  <br />
  of all of this.
</p>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // link text to inform users to click to expand
 var lnk = '[+]';
 // variable to look for stating it's a new reply
 var newrply = 'wrote:';
 // reply indicator (HTML escape code for ' > ' to exclude any HTML that might be found
 var isrply = '&gt; ';
 // collect html and split it into an array
 var txt = $('p').html().split('<br>');
 // flag showing that the text is within a reply block
 var rply = false;
 // cycle through each portion of text
 $.each(txt, function(i){
  // look for a new reply
  if (this.match(newrply)){
   // if within a reply and it finds a new reply, close previous
   var tmp = (rply) ? '</div>' : '';
   // add link
   txt[i] = tmp + txt[i] + ' <a href="#" class="replylink">' + lnk + '</a>';
   // go to next variable in array and add wrapper, this makes sure the <br> is outside the reply (formatting purposes)
   txt[i+1] = '<div class="reply">' + txt[i+1];
   // look for reply indicator or text that is <5 characters in length
   // (in the HTML above, the array value will have carriage return plus two spaces for each <br>)
  } else if (this.match(isrply) || txt[i].length < 5) {
   rply = true;
  } else {
   rply = false;
   // close the reply, add the close to the previous array element (most likely a <br>)
   txt[i-1] = txt[i-1] + '</div>';
  }
  // close the reply at the end of the array
  if(i == txt.length) {
   txt[i-1] = txt[i-1] + '</div>';
  }
 })
 // join the array and add it back
 $('p').html( txt.join('<br>') );
 // hide the replies
 $('.reply').hide();
 // add toggle view
 $('.replylink').click(function(){
  $(this).next().next('.reply').toggle();
  return false;
 })
})
```

I changed the link to just a '[+]' to toggle the view but I didn't bother changing it to '[-]' when the reply is open. I figured the code was getting long enough as it is for this example.

---

With the new code you posted, I had to make a few changes.

- It will now work with multiple posts (it processes each "div.post")
- It will now only find a new reply if the ">" is at the beginning of a new line
- It uses the rel tag to index each reply since the .next() function of jQuery will find "
  " and the number of these was variable
- One problem I had was with the click function, I ended up switching to .live because the click event was being triggered twice (I couldn't figure out why, but using live works).
- Lastly, I left the `<a name="" style="color: gray;"/>` in the code, but that is not properly formatted HTML... you can't close an `<a>` tag this way.

**New Update:**

- Fixed the script to work with IE, apparently IE uses `<BR>` instead of `<br>` so the split wasn't working. I ended up using `$.browser.msie` even though [it isn't recommended](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser). Also, the original script left unopened `</div>` which is why it broke in IE as well.
- The `rply` variable I used before wasn't updating between the iterations of the each function, so I moved it's value into a hidden input tag. I tried making it global, but it just wouldn't cooperate. It's probably not the ideal way to do this, so fix/adjust as you desire.

Required HTML

```
<input id="replyflag" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

Updated Code for IE & new [pastbin posting](http://pastebin.me/1332fdf503c8785db8d7e248ef7008c2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('div.post').each(function(){
  // link text to inform users to click to expand
  var lnk = '[+]';
  // variable to look for stating it's a new reply
  var newrply = 'wrote:';
  // reply indicator (HTML escape code for ' > ' to exclude any HTML that might be found
  var isrply = '&gt;';
  // IE capitalizes the <BR>, collect html and split it into an array
  var splt = ($.browser.msie) ? '<BR>' : '<br>';
  var txt = $(this).find('p:eq(0)').html().split(splt);
  // index of each reply in a post
  var indx = 0;
  // start <div> tag around contents, as the script automatically closes the tag, even without replies
  txt[0] = '<div>' + txt[0];
  // cycle through each portion of text
  $.each(txt, function(i){
   // look for a new reply
   if (this.match(newrply)){
    // if within a reply and it finds a new reply, close previous
    var tmp = ($('#replyflag').val()) ? '</div>' : '';
    // set the "within a reply flag" to true
    $('#replyflag').val(true);
    // increment index
    indx++;
    // add link, the rel attrib contains the index of the reply
    txt[i] = tmp + txt[i] + ' <a href="#" class="replylink" rel="' + indx + '">' + lnk + '</a>';
    // go to next variable in array and add wrapper, this makes sure the <br> is outside the reply (formatting purposes)
    txt[i+1] = '<div class="reply" rel="' + indx + '">' + txt[i+1];
   // look for reply indicator at the beginning of a line or text that is > 3 characters in length, if not there, turn off reply flag.
   } else if (this.substring(0,4)!=isrply | this.length > 3) {
    $('#replyflag').val(false);
   }
   // close the reply at the end of the array
   if (i >= txt.length-1) {
    txt[i] = txt[i] + '</div>';
   }
  })
  // join the array and add it back
  $(this).find('p:eq(0)').html( txt.join('<br>') );
  // hide the replies
  $('.reply').hide();
  // add toggle view (using live because sometimes the click event is called twice and the toggle appears to not work)
  $('.replylink').live('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.reply[rel=' + $(this).attr('rel') + ']').toggle();
   return false;
  })
 })
})
```

Comment: Brilliant work, thanks a lot for the effort you've put into this.

However, I can't get it to work properly on a production site.
This is the HTML of one post as sent by the server;
http://pastebin.me/c180b4042a51346bb1baf3d14593fdd0
In case of multiple instances, all posts' contents get replaced by text found in the first instance of <p>.

Again, thank you for the time you have dedicated to resolve this, the script is absolutely awesome and flawless when applied to properly formatted HTML.

Comment: I've updated the code to work with the HTML format you provided. If it doesn't work properly on a post with multiple replies, please share this code as well.

Comment: fudgey, I lack the vocabulary to adequately express my gratitude.

Thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: Eh, pity it doesn't work in IE6. You can't have it all I guess :)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have IE6 installed, but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, I got the script working with IE8... I haven't tested it with IE6, but I think it should work now. * Note * second bit of code has been updated and it now needs a hidden input tag to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe jquery parses text like this. You'll have to parse it yourself for lines that start with '>' and edit the string as you'd like. Then you can use jquery to act on the elements you added.